# WLAN Bridge connected over WLAN to the internet

Tags: wireless, bridge

I need to establish a WLAN Bridge over a distance of approximately 400m. I found this equipment: https://www.ligowave.com/products/apc-propeller-2

As I understand it needs to connect over LAN to the internetrouter. In this case i am not able to lay a cable to the outside from the internetrouter. So I need to connect over WLAN. The logical construct will be something like:

internetrouter (from ISP) <---WLAN----> WLAN Bridge <---400m distance---> WLAN Bridge <---LAN or WLAN ---> access point or end devices (like Laptop, samrtphone,...)

What kind of equipment do I need and how is this scenario called?

Comment: Why can't you just run some outdoor fiber to connect your two sites? It will be much more reliable, and it will have a much higher bandwidth.

Comment: It's not a big network. Actually there are just a few hosts that need to be connected. Also the internet bandwidth isn't high neither. It should be a solution as cheap as possible. Reliability is not important in this case

Comment: Maybe you should just get a separate Internet connection for the second site, then you can run a tunnel over the Internet between the two sites.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct internet connection possible. The second building is kind of isolated.

Comment: OK. I just don't think you are going to find the result acceptable with what you have planned. If you need to access resources (servers etc.) from the other site, it will probably be painfully slow, and I would stress that you should make sure to use a very good encryption since this is your business on the line.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need a point-to-point link. This means 2 directionnal WIFI antennas looking at each other and providing the transport between the two sites.

With two PtP devices in 5Ghz band, you can acheive like 100Mbps speed over 400m, more with the AC version (maybe 200Mbps, 300Mbps.. depends on many factors)

The device you link on your post is the same kind, but works with 2.4Ghz band, which is much much more crowded than 5Ghz, you have big chances to get a less reliable link with 2.4Ghz than 5Ghz.

As for the transport method, you can use

- bridging as you suggest, so both sides of the link will be in the same subnet, really easy to set up.
- routing (different subnets on both sides).This is preferred because you won't have unwanted traffic like broadcast or multicast "pollute" your link, but it's more complicated to set up than bridging and may require configuration on clients.

Comment: Is it possible to connect the device via WLAN with the existing network? Or has it to be a LAN connection?

Comment: Product and/or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @Benedict: the devices i proposed are only LAN-connected. But you can get another version with 2 wireless cards, 1 for the point-to-point link with directonal antenna and the other one for the "LAN'" side, with omni antenna. Unfortunalety i can't link you that product, Ron Maupin is watching us :p

Comment: @Ron: removed vendor specific links

Answer (score 0):

WiFi Bridging, you need a wireless bridge.  Basically, you purchase 2 wireless bridges which are a type of access point with a directional antenna.

Typically, each wireless bridge device will have a wired port (in addition to the wireless interface) that plugs in to the wired network.  However, there are dual mode access points that can both bridge and provide WLAN access.

The wireless bridge typically needs to be placed with line of sight to the other bridge and are usually installed external (outside the building).